# TS Understanding Type Inference Between Defining a Type Alias For A Function And With Defining Its Type At Function Declaration

Tags: typescript, type-alias

In the following functions, only the one using a defined type alias (*myFunc*) correctly narrows down the type of the **arg** within the IF...ELSE statement and I really don't know why this is the case:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
}

type MyFunc<T = Person | null> = (arg: T) => void;

const myFunc: MyFunc = arg => {
  if (arg === null) {
    const d = arg; // null
  } else {
    const d = arg; // Person
  }
};

const myFunc2: <T extends Person | null>(arg: T) => void = arg => {
  if (arg === null) {
    const d = arg; // T extends Person | null
  } else {
    const d = arg; // T & {}
  }
};
```

What's the reason for these two to work so differently?

EDITED
After reading @jcalz comment, I realized I need to be more specific with what I'm asking for the sake of avoiding confusion; basically, initially I was expecting `myFunc2` to work in the following way (again, thanks @jcalz for this code):

```js
const myFunc: (arg: Person | null) => void = arg => {
    if (arg === null) {
        const d = arg; // null
    } else {
        const d = arg; // Person
    }
};
```

So my question is, why in `myFunc2`, inside branch `arg === null`, the type of `arg` is still considering `Person` as part of it; I'm not sure whether the reason for this is that one uses `extends` and the other simply defines its type, (meaning that one is generic and the other not), and if that's the case, I still not sure why the type isn't narrowed down as to remove `Person` from it.

I also don't know why the type of the falsy(?) branch does not include either of those types (`null` and `Person`).

Comment: The type `MyFunc` (without an explicit type argument) is equal to `MyFunc<Person | null>` (because of your default type argument) and therefore it is the *non-generic* function type `(arg: Person | null) => void`.  On the other hand the type `<T extends Person | null>(arg: T)=>void` is a generic function type. One is generic, and one is not, and so they behave differently... does that fully address the question? If not, then the `T` in `MyFunc` is essentially a red herring and you might want to [edit] the code to [this version](//tsplay.dev/WYRagw) which is simpler but has the same issue.

Comment: Yeah you're right regarding one being generic and the other not, I think my question is (way?) more specific than what I originally thought; I'll edit my question to reflect that, but basically I'm interested on the generic one, why within the branch for `arg === null`, the type of `arg` still shows `Person` as part of it; the way I see it is that it's either one or the other

Comment: The issue is that [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) doesn't affect *generic type arguments*; so `T` itself never gets narrowed.  There are various open feature requests looking for an improvement to this, such as [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  Narrowing with generics behaves differently from narrowing with unions, and if I write up a full answer I can explain what it's doing, but at its core this is just a missing feature of TS.  Does that fully address it now? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: yeah that's correct, as long as one tries to implement it (the function), it won't work